# While Loops? Need Help Running New Program- Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop, quit

Okay, well for my job I have always used C++, but now they are wanting me to switch to Python.  So over the weekend I have been making very simple programs to get used to the new system.  I'm having trouble though with this program:

```
demand = input('What do you want to do: ')

option = 'Yes'

while option == 'Yes':


    if demand == 'add':
        print('Enter your two numbers...')

        a = int(input('First Number= '))
        b = int(input('Second Number= '))

        c = a + b

        print('Answer= %s' % c)

        option = input('Do you want to run agian?: ')


    if demand == 'subtract':
        print('Enter your two numbers...')

        a = int(input('First Number= '))
        b = int(input('Second Number= '))

        c = a - b

        print('Answer= %s' %c)

        option = input('Do you want to run agian?: ')


    if demand == 'multiply':
        print('Enter your two numbers...')

        a = int(input('Frist Number= '))
        b = int(input('Second Number= '))

        c = a * b

        print('Answer= %s' %c)

        option = input('Do you want to run agian?: ')


    if demand == 'divide':
        print ('Enter your two numbers...')

        a = int(input('First Number= '))
        b = int(input('Second Number= '))

        c = a / b

        print('Answer= %s' %c)

        option = input('Do you want to run agian?: ')



while option == 'No':
```

I know it is a simple program but I have a problem- I can get it to loop around when the user says 'Yes' after running the task but it stays on that task (ie. 'add' it will only run 'add' again and I want it to run from the beginning (so ask you what task you would like to preform).  Also, the program does not shut off by itself- you always have to manually quit it.
Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: You're never re-asking "What do you want to do?"... And what is that lonely `while option == 'No'` supposed to do?

Comment: @devnull Ctrl-C? Unplug the computer? Shotgun? There are many options! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK:

```
option = 'Yes'

while True:
    demand = input('What do you want to do: ')
    print('Enter your two numbers...')
    a = int(input('First Number= '))
    b = int(input('Second Number= '))
    c = 0
    if demand == 'add':
        c = a + b
    elif demand == 'subtract':
        c = a - b
    elif demand == 'multiply':
        c = a * b
    elif demand == 'divide':
        c = a / b

    print('Answer= %s' %c)
    option = input('Do you want to run agian?: ')
    if option != 'Yes':
        break
```

If you are using a loop, this means you *don't have* to repeat statements in every branch of `if`. So we read the `demand`, followed by the two numbers (since all operations require two numbers, there are no special things)